# How to create a shortcut key in PowerPoint 2016?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint

I am using PowerPoint 2016 and need to insert Microsoft Equations (the new latex-like type) a lot. Is there a way to assign a shortcut key (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) to do this instead of having to go through the menus/ribbons?

Searching around, I found that this seems to be [possible with MS Word](http://www.veodin.com/2013/01/12/case-study-3-custom-shortcuts-insert-formula-in-word-2013-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/), and for [Mac version of PowerPoint in Office 2011](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-Office-for-Mac-2011-1796E9A2-3748-4CF0-B163-24A65479CAA6?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bmpp). But what about Windows and 2016.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1260508/customize-keyboard-shortcuts-powerpoint-2016-windows). It is currently not possible, but there is a dedicated shortcut for inserting equations:

> For your convenience, hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd>  key, press
>   <kbd>N</kbd> , and then press <kbd>E</kbd>.
>
> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>  is the keyboard shortcut for switching to
>   the Insert tab and then pressing <kbd>E</kbd> afterward[s] brings up
>   the equation list.

As for the reason why Microsoft decided to not implement such a fundamental feature, I am completely stumped. I can only guess that some poor guy missed his deadline and that it will be reimplemented at some point.

Answer (score 0):

For me with Office 2016 on Windows 10 and a German keyboard layout,

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> inserts a new equation and triggers the equation editor in PowerPoint

(With shift pressed, the <kbd>+</kbd>-key is <kbd>*</kbd> on the German layout).