# Customize keyboard shortcuts powerpoint 2016 windows

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

In MS Word 2016, I can customize keyboard shortcuts as described [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Customize-keyboard-shortcuts-9a92343e-a781-4d5a-92f1-0f32e3ba5b4d). However, the same procedure cannot be applied to my Powerpoint 2016 software. Simply, the button "Customize" in step 3 of the aforementioned manual does not exist. Is there any way to assign a shortcut to, e.g., "insert equation" in PPT 2016?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Is there any way to assign a shortcut to, e.g., "insert equation" in PPT 2016?

There is no way to customise keyboards shortcuts in PowerPoint 2016.

However there is already a shortcut sequence for inserting equations.

> For your convenience, hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd>  key, press
>   <kbd>N</kbd> , and then press <kbd>E</kbd>.
>
> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>  is the keyboard shortcut for switching to
>   the Insert tab and then pressing <kbd>E</kbd> afterward[s] brings up
>   the equation list.

Source [Powerpoint 2016 Customize Keyboard Shortcuts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_win10-mso_2016/powerpoint-2016-customize-keyboard-shortcuts/2065a4e5-53ee-4bb2-bf4a-6e3bd938aef3)

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer. It is still a mystery to me why MS does not use the same options panel in all of their office products, which would naturally offer us the "customize shortcuts" option in all of their programs.

Answer (score 1):

I use different language versions of Microsoft Office on different computers (English, French and Spanish), so the differences in keyboard shortcuts and the inability to customize them in PowerPoint and Excel is very frustrating. The <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcut system described in another answer might work in some cases, but in my case, it is less than satisfactory. For example, something as simple as "Select All" in Spanish requires <kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>o</kbd>,<kbd>ó</kbd>,<kbd>e</kbd>. But because my keyboard does not have the accented ó, I can only do "Select All" with <kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>o</kbd>,<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>162</kbd>,<kbd>e</kbd>!

(Note that <kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>o</kbd> means "press and release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, and then press and release the <kbd>o</kbd> key"; whereas <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>162</kbd> means "press and hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while typing <kbd>162</kbd>, and then release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key".)

So, my workaround is to use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com) to create custom scripts. AutoHotkey lets you create almost any keyboard shortcut for almost anything. They have a [tutorial](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) to give you a good idea of what it can do.

If you're interested in that possibility, here's my PowerPoint shortcut script in AutoHotkey to give you a template for customization (note: my purpose is to use English shortcuts on Spanish Microsoft PowerPoint):

```
; MS PowerPoint
#IfWinActive ahk_exe POWERPNT.EXE
^a::Send {Alt DownR}o{ASC 162}e{Alt up}  ; select All
^b::Send ^n  ; Bold
^f::Send ^b  ; Find
^i::Send ^k  ; Italics
^h::Send ^l  ; find and replace
^s::Send ^g  ; Save file
```